# Facebook: how preload FQL works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

On "Advanced" tab of my app settings I've seen "Preload FQL" option with description "Facebook will send the result of these FQL queries as JSON-encoded POST parameters to your Canvas URL". I set it:

```
{
"test": {
"pattern": ".*",
"query": "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {*user*}"
}
}
```

but it doesn't post anything related into my app. I tried many ways but not successfully. Could someone point me out what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself: preload FQL isn't supported in the new API. Detailed here: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/issue/175

Comment: @Alexander Farber, that blogpost is year 2008. It still talks about fb_sig parameters which is actually old or might even be deprecated. I'm trying to figure out preload FQL for the new API.

Answer (score 0):

Preload FQL Query and Multiquery.
This section applies to FBML canvas pages, but ***not to websites or IFrame canvas pages***.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/performance/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve many of the same results that you did with FQL Preloading by using Grapi API [Batch Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) and FQL [Multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/). These two methods allow the same optimizations as FQL Preloading, but with a cleaner and more performant interface.

Also, the performance doc mentioned here has been removed because it contained of out-of-date information. The suggestions from that doc are now being interwoven throughout other parts of the documentation, in appropriate places.